# Outliers for Ratios

Tags: outliers, ratio

We have a large data set that includes two variables of interest (e.g., X and Y). We were interested in whether there were any outliers in the ratios of these two variables of interest across the whole of the data set. So, we calculated the ratios for the two variables of interest (i.e., X/Y and Y/X) across the entire data set. Then, we calculated the Q1, Q3, IQR, LBL (Q1 - (1.5 x IQR)), and UBL (Q3 + (1.5 x IQR)) for both sets of calculated ratios (i.e., X/Y and Y/X). Finally, we compared the values for each calculated ratio to the corresponding LBL and UBL across the entire data set. The output surprised us. For the same X and Y, there were X/Y ratios that counted as outliers. But, the corresponding Y/X ratios did not. If not a spreadsheet error on our part, what is the explanation for this phenomenon?

Comment: Which is the outlier in $0.01, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 10, 100$?  And in their reciprocals?  You might want to take logarithms of the ratios before identifying outliers

Comment: Are all your values X, Y positive? Ratios are very sensitive to small absolute values in the denominator (let alone sign changes - if they exist in your data). They are essentially asymmetric. The statistics Q1, Q3, IQR, LBL (Q1 - (1.5 x IQR)), and UBL (Q3 + (1.5 x IQR)) are all based on symmetry, so it's not a surprise that they identify different outliers for X/Y and Y/X. As said before, looking at log(X)-log(Y) may be better, however what exactly should count as "outlier" and what exactly to do depends on the data, their meaning, and what you then want to do with the identified outliers.

Comment: Consider using empirical percentiles.

Comment: @Lewian Thank you for the kind replies! Quick question, do you mean: 1) calculate X/Y across the data set; 2) calculate the log of X/Y across the data set; 3) calculate Y/X across the data set; 4) calculate the log of Y/X across the data set; 5) calculate the difference between the (2) and (4); 6) calculate the LBL and UBL; 7) Identify the outliers based on the LBL and UBL?

Comment: @Moon: As I wrote, what exactly should be done depends on the data, their meaning, and what you then want to do with the identified outliers. Without this information I can't tell you what to do. You haven't even responded yet to the first question whether all your values are positive. If they are, one option is to look for outliers in the absolute values of log(X)-log(Y), which are symmetric in X and Y. How good this option is in your case, however, depends on a number of things that I don't know.